# Cannot upload images, but can upload pdf to assets

Tags: pimcore

I have a weird thing in my new pimcore installation. I can only upload pdf files as assets (also .exe files) but no .jpg files. What can be causing this problem? Any toughts?

Comment: Please check ```/website/var/log/debug.log```

Comment: 2015-10-27T09:11:41+01:00 ERR (3):   9 MB | Pimcore\Controller\Action\Admin->init() [127]: Prevented access to /admin because there is no user in the session!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

please make sure You have php5-gd (or imagick) extension installed on your server. You can check for missing php extension and other software in Extras > System Info & Tools > System Requirements Check.

Comment: This was the problem. Thanks!